# Пишу приложение, которое выводит информацию о тексте на английском. Использую swing

Tags: java, строки, swing, textarea

Сейчас я хочу сделать подсчет слов в тексте.
Но проблема в том, что на любой текст выводится единица. Я могу ввести 30 слов, но выведет единицу.
Вот код

```
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by ТыжАдмин on 01.11.2016.
 */
public class Wind extends JFrame {

    public Wind() {


        Font font = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 12);
        Font font2 = new Font("ALGERIAN", Font.BOLD, 20);
        Font font3 = new Font("Berlin Sans FB", Font.BOLD, 15);
        Font font4 = new Font("Berlin Sans FB", Font.BOLD, 18);
        Font font5 = new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12);
        setTitle(" AI UK ");
        setBackground(Color.orange);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(999, 700, 1600, 950);
        setLayout(null);
        JButton x = new JButton("Обработать текст ");
        x.setBounds(512, 89, 190, 55);
        x.setFont(font);
        x.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        add(x);
        JLabel nfw = new JLabel("The number of words : ");
        nfw.setFont(font3);
        nfw.setBounds(800, 110, 290, 150);
        add(nfw);

        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(900, 193, 60, 50);
        add(textField);
        JTextArea txt = new JTextArea();
        txt.setBounds(32, 167, 700, 550);
        txt.setLineWrap(true);
        txt.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        txt.setFont(font2);
        add(txt);
        JLabel grk = new JLabel("Tne number of grammar constructions : ");
        grk.setFont(font4);
        grk.setBounds(800,201,355,180);
        add(grk);
        JLabel ps = new JLabel("Present Simple constructions : ");
        ps.setFont(font3);
        ps.setBounds(800,270,290,150);
        add(ps);
        JTextField psi = new JTextField();
        psi.setBounds(900,359,60,50);
        add(psi);
        JLabel pp = new JLabel("Present Perfect constructions : ");
        pp.setFont(font3);
        pp.setBounds(800,380,290,150);
        add(pp);
        JTextField ppe = new JTextField();
        ppe.setBounds(900,463,60,50);
        add(ppe);
        String s = txt.getText();
        String [] TAR = s.split(String.valueOf(new char[]{' '}));
        int tl;
        tl = TAR.length;
        x.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.setText(String.valueOf(tl));
            }
        });
```

Как можно вывести нормально все слова ? Есть ли в моем методе ошибки ?

Comment: Для оформления кода используйте отступы в четыре пробела или кнопку `{}`.

Comment: при нажатии на кнопку исполняется код внутри `actionPerformed`, соотв. в нем должен быть не только вывод содержимого `tl` но и вычисление ее значения (начиная с `txt.getText()`)

Answer (score 0):

Если разделителем слов является пробел, то используйте следующее:

```
String [] TAR = s.split(" ");
```

Мало кому хочется разбираться в коде, где имена переменных звучат как: x, pp, pl, ps и т.п. 
Будет не лишним прочитать книгу "Code convention", она не большая.

Answer (score 0):

Кол-во слов можно вывести так:

```
jtextField.setText(txt.getText().split(" ").length);
```

Люблю писать вложенные команды :-)